# On Honor 6x camera is slow to start. Any solutions?

Tags: huawei

It takes as long as 10-15 seconds at times. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** New culprit identified. The official Google Search app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) - the one that activates Google Assistant on the device, appears to do something that brings 6x to its knees. Once completely disabled, it manifested in a huge boost in the responsiveness of the device - camera included.

And since, admittedly, Google Search app is often useful, there is a Lite version that does not cause any issues - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.searchlite

**Original:**

Located a solution on XDA that solves this issue on a wide range of Honor devices (https://forum.xda-developers.com/p9/how-to/slow-camera-t3476554/page6)

"went to Settings, Apps, Advanced, Ignore Battery Optimisations and then Allowed the Camera App.

This has made a world of difference on mine, opens up in about 1 second now where before it was the 2 -5 seconds like people were reporting. "

And also:

"Thanks to safc1978 this really annoying problem is mostly fixed. I do still get some lag though, and wondered if it was partly caused by the Gallery app being slow to pull the little thumbnail image of the last photo taken (bottom left of screen).

I used safc1978's theory, and allowed "Gallery" to ignore optimisations too, and it seems to have made another small improvement."